# Unable to inspect element using XPath in Appium

Tags: java, mobile, appium

I am using the following code to inspect a textView and sendKeys:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException  {
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "HC48NMZ01687");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4.2");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "io.selendroid.testapp");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:\\Users\\QA Rahul Singh\\Desktop\\selendroid-test-app-0.17.0.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "HomeScreenActivity");

    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='my_text_fieldCD']")).sendKeys("rahul");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    driver.quit();
}
```

The activity I am trying to access looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Describe your problem clearly.

Comment: Does `driver.findElement(By.id("io.selendroid.testapp:id/my_text_field")).sendKeys("rahul");` work?

Comment: is my_text_fieldCD is common in other entities too?

Comment: @MandeepSingh NO CODE IS NOT WORKING

Comment: @ShubhamJain It is unique

Comment: Is your problem resolved?

Comment: @ShubhamJain no

Comment: After using testNG it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait first

First try to put wait for 7-8 sec using `Thread.sleep(7000);`. If it works then remove it and use explcit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(ad, 100);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By."YOUR LOCATOR")).sendKeys(username);
```

OR use `FluentWait`

```
WebElement waitsss(AppiumDriver driver, By elementIdentifier){
     Wait<WebDriver> wait =
                new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                                 .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

        return wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>()
                {
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                           return driver.findElement(elementIdentifier);
                    }
                });
}
```

If still not work may your XPath is not unique as it is valid XPath but may be not unique. You have resource id use it as below:-

```
//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'my_text_field')]
```

Hope it will help you :)